# Spydroid video streaming is not working in 4.2.2

Tags: android

Spydroid is running on android 5.0.2 properly with sound and video streaming. but when I implement same spydroid program in android 4.2.2 only sound streaming is working not video streaming. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: yeah what's solution